# Modify regex to exclude characters that occur at beginning

Tags: r, regex

Using below code I'm extracting a generated html link  :

```
mystr <- c("/url?q=http://www.mypage.html&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjgyMPj2pXXAhWB5CYKHXysDlsQqQIIKSgAMAg&usg=AOvVaw1VCvT8iznodM3l4xvc8CVq")

str_extract(mystr, "^.*(?=(&sa))")
```

This returns :

```
[1] "/url?q=http://www.mypage.html"
```

How to modify regex in order to exclude `/url?q=` ? So just `http://www.mypage.html` is returned ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the *beginning of the string* (i.e. `^`) with `http`,

```
stringr::str_extract(mystr, "http.*(?=(&sa))") 
#[1] "http://www.mypage.html"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use a base R `sub` solution to match up to the first `http` and capture it with any chsrs other than `&`:

```
sub(".*?(http[^&]*).*", "\\1", x)
```

You may precise the pattern to match only after `q=`  aftrr `.*?`.

**Details**

- `.*?` - any 0+ chars as few as possible,
- `(http[^&]*)` - capturing group #1 matching `http` and then any zero or more chars other than `&`
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

The `\1` is a replacement backreference to the Group 1 value.